# Salesforce1 - update icon for custom button

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-button

I have added a custom detail button to the Order page layout and would like to change the icon from the 'spanner' to something else in Salesforce1. Is this possible? I've attached a screenshot for reference.

Also, wondering if there is a way to add a text message to highlight the buttons usecase? Is this possible??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue and haven't seen any solutions. The work around would be to create a custom action just for Salesforce1, perhaps replicating the action of the button with JavaScript that redirects the user to the Visualforce page.

I've just submitted an idea to Salesforce for this fix if you'd like to vote for it:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DoTIAA0

Until then I'll likely need to replicate buttons with actions. With Summer '15, it looks like there's a new option on the page layout that allows you to override which actions/buttons are shown on Salesforce1 vs the desktop so we won't have to have duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @SecondJon. I did start using Actions then needed to add to Orders which for some inexplicable reason doesn't allow actions. What I ended up doing was having a VF page which contained code to show/hide a link to the VF that I wanted to navigate to. Disappointed in what SF1 provides in this area...

Comment: @RichardDurrant - there is Javascript you can use to redirect the user. We had our own order object before Salesforce released theirs - we have a number of actions and buttons on them, I'm always disappointed when the block actions from certain objects (Events are like this too)